# How to Implement Firebase Phone Authentication for Subsequent Logins with Phone Number and Password?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

We're currently integrating Firebase Phone Authentication into our application flow. However, we encounter a scenario where we register the user with their phone number and verify the OTP and save the user's phone number, password and username in firebase fire store collection name "users". After this initial registration, we aim to enable users to log in using their phone number and a password in subsequent sessions. Could anyone provide guidance on how to implement this functionality effectively within Firebase Phone Authentication?

we aim to enable users to log in using their phone number and a password in subsequent sessions. Could anyone provide guidance on how to implement this functionality effectively within Firebase Phone Authentication?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in provider for Firebase to allow the user to sign in with a phone number and password.

But you can build your own provider that takes such credentials by following the documentation on [using Firebase with a custom authentication system](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/custom-auth). A good starting point would be this [example of a username+password sign-in provider](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/Node-1st-gen/username-password-auth).